# Android map shows blue screen instead of map

Tags: android

I have code for displaying two locations on the map with markers but it shows the markers only, and instead of the map it shows a blue screen only. I am running on mobile, not emulator.

My code:

```
public class HelloGoogleMaps3 extends MapActivity {
    private MapView map=null;
    private MyLocationOverlay me=null;

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.main);

        map=(MapView)findViewById(R.id.map);

        map.getController().setCenter(getPoint
                (40.76793169992044,-173.98180484771729));
        map.getController().setZoom(17);
        map.setBuiltInZoomControls(true);

        Drawable marker=getResources().getDrawable(R.drawable.marker);

        marker.setBounds(0, 0, marker.getIntrinsicWidth(),
                        marker.getIntrinsicHeight());

        map.getOverlays().add(new SitesOverlay(marker));

        me=new MyLocationOverlay(this, map);
        map.getOverlays().add(me);
    }

    @Override
    public void onResume() {
        super.onResume();

        me.enableCompass();
    }       

    @Override
    public void onPause() {
        super.onPause();

        me.disableCompass();
    }       

    @Override
    protected boolean isRouteDisplayed() {
        return(false);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onKeyDown(int keyCode, KeyEvent event) {
        if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_S) {
            map.setSatellite(!map.isSatellite());
            return(true);
        }
        else if (keyCode == KeyEvent.KEYCODE_Z) {
            map.displayZoomControls(true);
            return(true);
        }

        return(super.onKeyDown(keyCode, event));
    }

    private GeoPoint getPoint(double lat, double lon) {
        return(new GeoPoint((int)(lat*1000000.0),
                            (int)(lon*1000000.0)));
    }

    private class SitesOverlay extends ItemizedOverlay<OverlayItem> {
        private List<OverlayItem> items=new ArrayList<OverlayItem>();
        private Drawable marker=null;

        public SitesOverlay(Drawable marker) {
            super(marker);
            this.marker=marker;

            items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint
                    (40.748963847316034,-173.96807193756104),
                                "UN", "United Nations"));
            items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint
                    (40.76866299974387,-173.98268461227417),
                                "Lincoln Center",
                                "Home of Jazz at Lincoln Center"));
            items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint
                    (40.765136435316755,-173.97989511489868),
                                "Carnegie Hall",
                        "Where you go with practice, practice, practice"));
            items.add(new OverlayItem(getPoint
                    (40.70686417491799,-174.01572942733765),
                                "The Downtown Club",
                        "Original home of the Heisman Trophy"));

            populate();
        }

        @Override
        protected OverlayItem createItem(int i) {
            return(items.get(i));
        }

        @Override
        public void draw(Canvas canvas, MapView mapView,
                                        boolean shadow) {
            super.draw(canvas, mapView, shadow);

            boundCenterBottom(marker);
        }

        @Override
        protected boolean onTap(int i) {
            Toast.makeText(HelloGoogleMaps3.this,
                                items.get(i).getSnippet(),
                                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return(true);
        }

        @Override
        public int size() {
            return(items.size());
        }
    }
}
```

What did I do wrong?

Comment: That location is in the middle of the Pacific Ocean. The ocean is blue. Oops :)

Answer (score 1):

That could mean either of the following two things:

a. Your API Key is incorrect

b. Your coordinates are set to (0, 0) and the map marker is pointing in the ocean. Try zooming the map in. You'd probably see the land. :)

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you get a location from the location manager and try and use the coordinates without first converting them:

```
Location location = locationManager.getLastKnownLocation(LocationManager.GPS_PROVIDER);
// location.getLatitude() is, say, 56.8751841974
// location.getLongitude() is, say, -3.9548756201
GeoPoint mapPoint = new GeoPoint((int)(location.getLatitude() * 1E6), (int)(location.getLongitude() * 1E6));
```

Basically, you need to multiply the values by 1 million to map to the correct coordinates.

Answer (score 0):

You can customize the MapView color with different sets of coordinates, for example :

- 40.76793169992044,-173.98180484771729 is [blue](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=40.76793169992044,-173.98180484771729&z=8), as you experienced
- -77.199943,11.913063 is [light gray](http://maps.google.com/maps?q=-77.199943,11.913063&z=8)
- 75.913515,-30.443115 is [green](http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=75.913515,-30.443115&z=8)
- 43.318418,11.331644 is [Siena](http://maps.google.com/maps?ll=43.318418,11.331644&z=16)